# Having issue with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datatables

Using datatables on my project. Got several questions about it

Please take a look at [this page](http://tural.no-ip.org/?page=db)

[image]

1. Used tabletools plug-in to create new buttons in instrument panel. But why "Show xx entry" drop-down list hidden? How can I unhide it? Take a look at [default table](http://www.datatables.net/index) You'll see what I mean by "Show xx entry" drop-down list.
2. Head rows moved to the left. They are not staying at right place. For Ex. 1 must be under Item No and so on. How can I fix it?

Comment: Rather than ask us to go to a page, please post _only_ the relevant portions of the code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is an impossible question, since you've posted no source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the page source, the header row:

```
<tr> <th>Item No</th>
```

You don't have a header column above the green button, so they are all off by one.

Comment: green buttons generated by javascript. take a look http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: So?  You need the same number of headers as data columns or they will not line up.  It doesn't matter if it's markup or JavaScript.